# Typedef after incomplete type definition

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-errors, typedef, redeclaration

I'm need to declare incomplete type (may it be `siginfo_t`) in header, and in source  import some system header (`sys/signal.h`), that defines that type.

So, here is the problem:

```cpp
// a.h
struct siginfo_t;
void foo(siginfo_t*);
```

```cpp
// a.cpp
#include "a.h"
#include <signal.h> 
void foo(siginfo_t* x) { /* implementation */ };
```

But in signal.h it is defined like:

```
typedef struct siginfo_t { /* */ } siginfo_t;
```

Compiler error: `error: typedef redefinition with different types ('struct siginfo_t' vs 'siginfo_t')`.

How to achieve no errors there? Thanks!

Comment: Why can't `a.h` include `signal.h`? Are you trying to avoid a circular dependency with a forward declaration? Is this C or C++?

Comment: @Саша Новожилов Provide a minimal complete program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You can declare `typedef struct siginfo_t siginfo_t;`, though I'm not sure if the standard says anything about redeclaring standard library types.

Comment: @tadman it is a not good idea to include system-dependent files in headers. So, this is a good practice to use incomplete types. It is not a circular dependecy/etc. It's only about written above.

Comment: If `signinfo_t` is something specific to a particular OS, then that function is as well, and the whole thing should be walled off inside an `#ifdef`. You don't just forward declare some random thing to appease the compiler.

Comment: Again, is this C or C++?

Comment: You really have to decide if you're programming C or C++. They are two very different languages, and have very different behavior in this specific case.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow minimal complete program is a two files (a.h and a.cpp), that described in question. `a.h` have also `#pragma once` at the top of file.

Comment: @tadman It is C++

Comment: Why don't you include `<signal.h>` in your file `a.h`?

Comment: It's nothing wrong with system-dependent header files in your own header file. Besides, `<signal.h>` is a standard C header file, so should be available everywhere. And you still use a POSIX specific structure from that header file, so your code isn't portable anyway, making the issue kind of moot. Just include the `<signal.h>` header file in your header file, and be done with it.

Answer (score 5):

In the header `<sys/siginfo.h>` the typedef name `siginfo_t` is an alias for an unnamed structure

```
typedef struct {
    int si_signo;
    int si_code;
    union sigval si_value;
    int si_errno;
    pid_t si_pid;
    uid_t si_uid;
    void *si_addr;
    int si_status;
    int si_band;
} siginfo_t;
```

But you introduced the same alias name for named structure

```
typedef struct siginfo_t { /* */ } siginfo_t;
```

So the compiler issues the error

> error: typedef redefinition with different types ('struct siginfo_t'
> vs 'siginfo_t')

because you may not introduce the same alias name for a named structure and an unnamed structure. These structures are different  types.

Comment: The second code part was from sys/siginfo.h.... It has a alias as "signal.h"

Comment: I'm introduced siginfo_t only in file a.h.

Comment: @СашаНовожилов But you included the both headers in a.cpp. So the  translation unit have two different declarations of the same name. See your code example // a.cpp
#include "a.h"
#include <signal.h> In any case it is a bad idea to use the same name for two different entities.

Answer (score -2):

So, there is the right approach:

```
// a.h
#pragma once
extern "C" {
    struct siginfo;
}
void foo(siginfo*);
```

```
// a.cpp
#include "a.h"
#include <sys/siginfo.h>
void foo(siginfo* x) { /* */ };
```

Comment: @ Саша Новожилов Now actually you have the same name with "C" linkage and "C++" linkage. It is a bad idea. As I already wrote you shall not redeclare the same name.